# Is it needed to stop Spring Boot application during Flyway migration?

Tags: spring-boot, database-migration, flyway

I have `Spring Boot` application container deployed in `k8s`. And I have separate container with `Flyway` image. I need to make a migration in `PostgreSQL` DB. Do I need to stop the `Spring Boot` application container before the migration? Or the application will automatically catch the changes in the DB and fail in case of inappropriate DB schema?

Comment: it's a bit unclear why do you need to have a separate flyway container?

Comment: If you add the Flyway dependency to your spring boot app, it will pick it up when starting the application and will work its magic. It also should be quite strait forward to move it as it will read from the DB which file has been already processed. See 85.5 under https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html

Comment: I was asking about a specific case because otherwise, you can just use flyway in combination with spring and it will do everything you need

Comment: I will have a look on it, thank you both)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my special case behavior is the following: 
It is not needed to stop the `Spring Boot` pod to make a migration. In case of wrong schema - requests will return `500` error and the pod will not restart. And when the schema will be fixed, the application will start to work properly without any additional restarts.

PS: pay attention on the question's comments